# Can Pulse Audio emulate a virtual PC Speaker?

Tags: virtualbox, audio, pulseaudio

I would like to know if it's possible to emulate a virtual PC Speaker through PulseAudio.

[I am running TempleOS which *only* supports a PC Speaker as a guest to a VirtualBox machine](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50260790/124486). As far as I can see, VirtualBox does not support PC Speaker Emulation, like VM Ware does. VirtualBox supports only PC Speaker Pass Through, so I would like Pulse Audio to emulate and make available a PC Speaker device that I could use in Pass Through.

As a test case, I think if things like `beep` worked, my Virtual Box install of TempleOS would work.

I've tried with and without the module `pcspkr`, I do not believe that this emulates anything. I think it's a driver to enable it if it exists, as the module's descriptions seems to imply "PC Speaker beeper driver".

```
lsmod | grep -i pcspkr
pcspkr                 16384  0
```

Comment: What happens if you instruct VirtualBox now to "pass through"  the PC speaker - maybe you do already have a PC speaker interface in the host (alongside PA)?

Comment: @Ned64 I just get no sound. I don't have a PC Speaker on the host, so I need Pulse Audio to virtualize it.

Comment: Please try `modprobe pcspkr` as root, then see whether the module is loaded (`lsmod | grep pcspkr`). Post the output in the question please.

Comment: @Ned64 updated with info

Comment: OK, please (install and) try the `beep` program/command as root. Is there a sound? Then the device exists.

Comment: Do you *have* to run it on VirtualBox? AFAIK Qemu emulates various audio hardware including the PC speaker, and can forward it to various host methods including Pulseaudio (untested). Also, the question should be if *Virtualbox* can emulate the PC speaker - Pulseaudio certainly can't emulate accesses inside Virtualbox to the I/O port where the PC speaker sits.

Comment: https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/627 : looks it's not supported by virtualbox (but since sound is supported there's a link to have the beep routed to pulseaudio *in a guest running X11, not the host*, this can be misleading)